# How to Edit an Order on Magento After it is Shipped

Tags: magento-1.7

Is there a way to edit an order on Magento after its shipped.

Instances where customers return the products and change it for another product.

Thank You

Currently on Magento 1

Answer (score 0):

You can refund this order making sure checking the flag to return the qty of the refunded product on the inventory again, and create a new order from the admin with the requested product.

Comment: Hello Arjus, Thank You for your response. What if we dont want to return the money to the customer because he also wants to use the money to pay for the changed product. Do we do offline refund for this?

Comment: yes you can do an offline refund and you keep the money

Comment: Thank You for your help Arjus